# How can I manage multiple memberships for an individual with multiple addresses for each membership?

Tags: civimember, contacts, custom-fields, addresses, organization

I'm using civi memberships to, among other things, manage a subscription service. Two problems we're having:

1. We have five subscription types, one of which is an annual subscription. These are all set up under one organisation. Some of our customers have two annual subscriptions. My concern is that setting up a second organisation with a second page to buy these subscriptions will be too messy. Is there a way to allow customers to purchase two memberships without setting up a second organisation?
2. We often provide other services for our contacts and some of our subscribers receive their subscription at a different address to the address listed for other services or a second subscription. Is there a way to allow multiple addresses without causing issues?

Comment: I don't think you should need to set up a different page to have a Membership connected to a different Organisation. I just changed 'student' memb type to belong to another organisation at https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=2. Works as expected

Comment: If you use Location Type = Postal for your subs you should then be able to use other Location Types for the other needs